# How do I run previously set up environment in django?

Tags: python, django

I am very new to django I set up an environment and now later when I try open the environment it is not running.
Please help.
Sorry if this a noob question I am very new with django

Comment: How did you set up the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you did not source the environment.

On Mac/Linux do:
'source <path to the venv you created>/bin/activate'